# Error when saving wordpress

Tags: php

I have just installed wordpress. I unzipped the files, entered database and admin info, and it all works fine.
However, when I try and make a design change in customizer, then click save and publish, it does nothing (remains the same).

I have tried as recommended increasing php memory.

I also notice I get this error in console when pressing save:

```
    HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). 
(XHR)POST - http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

This is a completely fresh install, so not sure how this is possible. When I visit admin-ajax.php in browser, there is an output of a 0.

Comment: When you setup WordPress did you enter `example.com` as the domain?

Comment: no, it didn't offer for me to

Comment: In the admin go to wp Settings -> General and make sure your URLs are correct.